# Entity Framework Core Select does not read writes from another process

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following class that gets a DbContext from dependency injection:

```
public DA(CustomDbContext db){
    this.db=db;
}

public void AddEntry(Entry entry){
    db.Entries.Add(entry);
    db.SaveChanges();   
}

public Entry SelectEntry(int id){
    return db.Entries.First(e=>e.Id==id);
}
```

This class is registered in dependency injection with `AddTransient`. The problem is that when I do the following:

```
var entry=new Entry{Stuff="stuff"};
da.AddEntry(entry);
await Task.Delay(2000);
var entryWithRecentChanges=da.SelectEntry(entry.Id);
```

I don't get the changes other processes wrote to that entry. I know `SaveChanges` creates a new transaction, but I thought that transaction only lasted for that call. The other process doesn't use transactions as far as I know. How can I force Entity Framework to get the latest data for that entry? I am using Entity Framework Core and SQL Server.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the SQL statements which are generated by the entity framework of the two instances/threads/processes when you run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using AsNoTracking fixed the issue:

```
public Entry SelectEntry(int id){
    return db.Entries.AsNoTracking().First(e=>e.Id==id);
}
```